# Keeping hint while don't type anything in EditText android

Tags: android

I would like to pass intent from firstActivity to second secondActivity using startActivityForResult

But in the case that I don't type anything in EditText, result in second activity still show hint of EditText, but if I type some, the result is going be what I type.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can put a null check to the variable. If the value is null. Means no one typed anything send the hint as "hard coded" in the code.

Like this

```
if (editText.val() == null || editText.val() == '') {
   editText.setValue("your Hint"); 
}
```

Please code it accordingly. Its just the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using `EditText.setText("your intent");` in onTextChange .
Try to use it in onCreate method